# Files are added to my project folder but not found in Xcode

Tags: xcode, git

I have a project in Xcode. I use git, and a partner did a commit. Now, I have added my branch, but some files are in my project folder but do not appear in the project in Xcode.

I'm trying add them from build phases, but the classes aren't found.

How can I add all files?

Comment: This happens a lot with merge conflicts in the project file...

Comment: Yes.. is a big problem? could be fixed easily?